# Why is there a minus in the 2ˆ(–delta delta CT) method (qPCR)

Tags: normalization, qpcr

Question: Why is there a minus in the `2ˆ(–delta delta CT)` formula?

My line of thoughs:

Consider `Ct` values of some pPCR experiment (some gene of interest X and a reference gene REF is measured under some experiment condition and a control condition).

1. The delta CT (`dCt`) would correspond to normalized <s>expression</s> Ct of X against REF of both conditions. (dCt = X-REF)
2. The delta delta CT (`ddCt`) would then correspond the the difference of the dCt of the experiment condition minus the dCt of the control condition.

=> If ddCT > 0 then the gene of interest is <s>upregulated</s> downregulated (Ct is antiproportional to gene expression). (the difference of the dCt in the experiment condition is larger than in the control condition)

But now: the ratio `R = 2ˆ(–delta delta CT)` would then correspond to a value smaller than 1 (because of the minus).

I read sentences like

> "We see a 10% decrease of expression (R=0.9)..."

<s>But actually the raw data clearly shows a upregulation</s>... This is confusing since only the ratio R decreases by 10% but the this would correspond to an increase of raw expression...

<s>I could interprete R as the ratio of the control against the gene of interest. But why not the other way around?</s>

**Edit: Ct is antiproportional to gene expression => dCt does not directly reflect the gene expression.**

> Sources:
>
> https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-020-03696-y
>
> "We can predict that a plant with a hormone concentration of
> 8.85 pg/mL would have an expression of Gene G that is 27% (̂ =0.73) lower than that of plants with average hormone concentration" (just
> below equation 8)
>
> But clearly in Fig. 3a you can see that the expression at 8.85 is
> obviously higher than with average hormone concentration (x0 = 9.85)

Comment: Perhaps this pdf of the ddCt package helps: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ddCt/inst/doc/rtPCR.pdf . See equations 6, 7 and 8.

Comment: ok I found the reason: Ct is antiproportional to the gene expression. Therefore the statements from the paper are correct. But thank you for your link, very nice derivation